# Let $d = gcd(a,b)$. Prove that if $a$ divides $bc$, then $a$ divides $dc$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I tried $bc = ak$, where $b$, $c$, $k$, are integers.

Then $a = dr b= dj$, where $a$, $b$, $d$, $j$, $r$ are integers.
\begin{align}
bc &= ak\\
djc &= ak\\
dc &= (ak)/j\\
dc &= a(k/j)
\end{align}
I thought this was okay but it is wrong because $(k/j)$ MAY NOT be an integer. if it was proven $k/j$ yields an integer, I would be done but I am lost. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $\gcd(a,b)=d$, then there exists integers $m,n$ such that $am+bn=d$. Using this and the fact that $a$ divides $bc$, what happens when you multiply $am+bn=d$ by $c$?

Comment: I got it, thank you very much!